# How much do I "wastefully spend" per support or rope?

Tags: bridge-constructor-portal

The game obviously tells you at the end of each level,

> You wastefully spent: $x

For example, it cost me $10100 to complete level one.

How is this calculated? Testing appears that it matters based on distance in addition to how many supports/ropes you have, but how much?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some science.

---

Placing a support costs 400$, and then 100$ for each dot.

After that, it seems like each support can go up to 12 dots away, and can have positions that are sort of half that'll just add 50$.

Switching to roadway doesn't affect prices.

So, support prices go from 500$* to 1700$.

---

Placing a rope costs 300$, and then 50$ for each dot.

There aren't any size limitations for ropes.

Rope prices start from 350$*.

---

Count of people dead, or test vehicle count doesn't seem to affect the amount you wastefully spend.

---

*: as you can't place a 0 sized support or rope, minimum price is "starting price + (1 * dot price)"

Comment: Vehicle count is a good idea, I didn't even think of testing that.

Comment: If supports can go up to 12 dots why is the max price for supports 1700? Would it not be 400+12*100 = 1600?

Comment: @Chris right, yes. it was me being doing incorrect maths, but I am pretty sure I saw 1650 increase on full size. So... I'll investigate further.